# Finding equivalance classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The relation ~ on $\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $x$ ~ $y$ iff ${x}^2$ = ${y}^2$. Explicity find the equivalence classes [0],[4],[-72].

Can someone please help me understand how to find equivalence classes. I have not clue how to do this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: You may start reading the definition of your relation, for example. So the elements in relation with $0$ are those $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $y^2 = 0$. Hence $y = 0$ and then $[0] = \{0\}$. The elements in relation with $4$ are those $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $y^2 = 16$. Then $[4] = \{\pm 4\}$. What about the last one?.

Answer (score 1):

If $c \in \mathbb Z$, then $[c]$ is the set of all integers $d$ such that $c^2=d^2$. For $c=4$, the equality becomes $d^2= 4^2 = 16$. What integers $d$ satisfy this equality? How about the other values of $c$?